# Remove brackets if the content inside is a number

Tags: python, regex, replace, conditional-statements

Is there any way to remove the brackets `()` if the content inside `.isnumeric()`

I do know a little bit of RegEx but I'm unable to find a way to do it using RegEx.

Example:

```
input = '((1)+(1))+2+(1+2)+((2))'
output = somefunction(input)
```

Here the output should look like

```
(1+1)+2+(1+2)+2
```

Comment: Hint: you want to replace the expression `(\d+)` with just the `\d+`… (capturing groups, replacement with matching group content…)

Comment: the content inside the brackets should be numeric so here `2` is  numeric but `1+1` is not

Comment: @deceze can you please explain your comment.

Comment: You’re thinking about it too complicated. “Trying to remove parentheses if the content is numeric” is a difficult approach. Think in terms of replacing any string that matches *”parens number parens”* with just the matched *number*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

x = '((1)+(1))+2+(1+2)+((2))'
re.sub(r'(\()([\d*\.]+)(\))', r"\2", x)

"""
or
re.sub(r'\(([\d*\.]+)\)', r"\1", x) #  @deceze
"""
```

But this will give you
`(1+1)+2+(1+2)+(2)`

Can maybe use `re.subn` to do this until number of replacements are 0

Comment: Thanks for the asnwers. If possible can you please provide the answer with `re.subn` It would be really helpful :)

Comment: Can refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn. Can use re.subn just like re.sub (in a while loop) and use its return value number_of_subs_made to check when to stop.

Comment: There’s no need to capture the parentheses, that just makes this regex harder to read.

Comment: @deceze Have updated the answer.